# 'CustomerPurchaseOrder' object has no attribute 'get_user_visible_fields'

Tags: python, django

I am doing  import-export to excel in my admin.py, every time i click the import button i receive this error **'CustomerPurchaseOrder' object has no attribute 'get_user_visible_fields'** i dont know what is wrong with my code, i been following the documentation (below). did i miss something in my code?.

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrderResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerPurchaseOrder
        fields = ('profile', 'customer_Purchase_Order_Detail', 'process', 'deliverySchedule', 'deliveryDate', 'paymentmethod',
    'requestedDate',)
class CustomerPurchaseOrderAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ("process", "deliverySchedule", "inputdate")
    list_display = (
    'profile', 'customer_Purchase_Order_Detail', 'process', 'deliverySchedule', 'deliveryDate', 'paymentmethod',
    'requestedDate',)
    ordering = ('id','requestedDate')
    resource_class = CustomerPurchaseOrder
```

this is my models.py

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Customer,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Client Account")
    customerdeliveryaddress = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDeliveryAddress, 
                                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                                verbose_name="Delivery Address")
    customer_Purchase_Order_Detail = models.ForeignKey('CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail',
                                                       on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                                       verbose_name="Customer Purchase Order")
    process = models.ForeignKey('Process', 
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                verbose_name="Process")
    attachment = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    requestedDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    deliverySchedule = models.ForeignKey(DeliverySchedule, 
                                         on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                         verbose_name="Schedule")
    deliveryDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    instructionToSeller = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    paymentmethod = models.ForeignKey('PaymentMethod',
                                      on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                      verbose_name="Process")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    recordStatus = models.ForeignKey(RecordStatus,
                                     on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True.)
    .....
```

[image]

this is the documentation i follow https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html

this is my full traceback

Environment:
Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py" in import_action
  334.         context['fields'] = [f.column_name for f in resource.get_user_visible_fields()]

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/customAdmin/customerpurchaseorder/import/
Exception Value: 'CustomerPurchaseOrder' object has no attribute 'get_user_visible_fields'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `resource_class` in your `CustomerPurchaseOrderAdmin` to `CustomerPurchaseOrderResource` and not `CustomerPurchaseOrder` as per the linked documentation.